# Why is stage.fullScreenWidth returning iPhone values on my iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, flash, retina-display, starling-framework

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my game to run at the proper resolution on an iPad Air.

I'm using FlashDevelop and the scaffold_mobile template. The problem is that

`stage.fullScreenWidth` and `stage.fullScreenHeight`
 are returning **960x640**. Those are retina iPhone values! My understanding is that they should be returning **2048x1536** on my retina iPad.

Because of this, the annoying little "1x" and "2x" scale circles show up in the bottom right corner of my app on the iPad and everything is much smaller than it should be.

Any advice on this? I tried messing around with the `[SWF( width="...", height="..."]`
 values, but that seemed to have no effect.

Thanks in advance!

For completeness, here's the entirety of my Main.as class which is taken pretty much right from scaffold_mobile:

```
package
{

import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import starling.core.Starling;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.textures.Texture;
import starling.utils.AssetManager;
import starling.utils.RectangleUtil;
import starling.utils.ScaleMode;
import starling.utils.formatString;

[SWF( width="1024", height="768", frameRate="60" )]
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    // We embed the "Ubuntu" font. Beware: the 'embedAsCFF'-part IS REQUIRED!!!
    //[Embed(source="/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf", embedAsCFF="false", fontFamily="Ubuntu")]
    //private static const UbuntuRegular:Class;

    // Startup image for SD screens
    [Embed(source="/../assets/2048/smallBGs/backgroundSmall.png")]
    private static var Background:Class;

    // Startup image for HD screens
    [Embed(source="/../assets/2048/bigItems/background.png")]
    private static var BackgroundHD:Class;

    private var mStarling:Starling;

    public function Main()
    {
        // set general properties

        var stageWidth:int   = 980;// Constants.STAGE_WIDTH;
        var stageHeight:int  = 566; // Constants.STAGE_HEIGHT;
        var iOS:Boolean = Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("iOS") != -1;

        Starling.multitouchEnabled = true;  // useful on mobile devices
        Starling.handleLostContext = !iOS;  // not necessary on iOS. Saves a lot of memory!

        // create a suitable viewport for the screen size
        //
        // we develop the game in a *fixed* coordinate system of 320x480; the game might
        // then run on a device with a different resolution; for that case, we zoom the
        // viewPort to the optimal size for any display and load the optimal textures.

        var fullScreen:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        trace("FULLSCREEN: " + fullScreen );

        var viewPort:Rectangle = RectangleUtil.fit(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight),
            fullScreen,
            ScaleMode.SHOW_ALL);

        trace("VIEWPORT: " + viewPort );    

        // create the AssetManager, which handles all required assets for this resolution

        var scaleFactor:int = viewPort.width < 480 ? 1 : Config.SD_SCALE; // midway between 320 and 640
        var appDir:File = File.applicationDirectory;
        var assets:AssetManager = AssetLoader.ASSETS; //new AssetManager(scaleFactor);

        assets.verbose = Capabilities.isDebugger;

        // While Stage3D is initializing, the screen will be blank. To avoid any flickering,
        // we display a startup image now and remove it below, when Starling is ready to go.
        // This is especially useful on iOS, where "Default.png" (or a variant) is displayed
        // during Startup. You can create an absolute seamless startup that way.
        //
        // These are the only embedded graphics in this app. We can't load them from disk,
        // because that can only be done asynchronously (resulting in a short flicker).
        //
        // Note that we cannot embed "Default.png" (or its siblings), because any embedded
        // files will vanish from the application package, and those are picked up by the OS!

        var backgroundClass:Class = scaleFactor == 1 ? Background : BackgroundHD;
        var background:Bitmap = new backgroundClass();
        Background = BackgroundHD = null; // no longer needed!

        background.x = viewPort.x;
        background.y = viewPort.y;
        background.width  = viewPort.width;
        background.height = viewPort.height;
        background.smoothing = true;
        addChild(background);

        // launch Starling

        mStarling = new Starling(Game, stage, viewPort);
        mStarling.stage.stageWidth  = stageWidth;  // <- same size on all devices!
        mStarling.stage.stageHeight = stageHeight; // <- same size on all devices!
        mStarling.simulateMultitouch  = false;
        mStarling.enableErrorChecking = Capabilities.isDebugger;

        mStarling.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED,
            function(event:Object, app:Game):void
            {
                mStarling.removeEventListener(starling.events.Event.ROOT_CREATED, arguments.callee);
                removeChild(background);
                background = null;

                var bgTexture:Texture = Texture.fromEmbeddedAsset(
                    backgroundClass, false, false, scaleFactor);

                app.start( bgTexture, assets );
                mStarling.start();
            });

        // When the game becomes inactive, we pause Starling; otherwise, the enter frame event
        // would report a very long 'passedTime' when the app is reactivated. 

        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(
            flash.events.Event.ACTIVATE, function (e:*):void { mStarling.start(); });

        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(
            flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE, function (e:*):void { mStarling.stop(true); });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=10092

You have to uncomment the `<string>2</string>` line in the iPhone section of `application.xml`. Should be line 29 (or thereabouts).

Answer (score 0):

With Starling the stageWidth is the viewport with not the device width

To get the real device with use:

```
 import flash.system.Capabilities;

 var stageWidth:int = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
 var stageHeight:int = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```